# UPDATE from inner complex SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE DB4010.dbo.EntityStagedData
SET
EntityData = (
    SELECT 
        geo.City + ' ' + geo.Description + ' ' + geo.Street + ' ' +
        geo2.City + ' ' + geo2.Description + ' ' + geo2.Street
    FROM DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplates templates
        INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateClients clients 
        ON clients.RouteTemplateID = templates.RouteTemplateID
        INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopMasters masters 
        ON masters.RouteTemplateClientID = clients.RouteTemplateClientID
        INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopDetails details 
        ON details.RouteTemplateStopID = masters.PickupStopID
        INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopDetails details2 
        ON details2.RouteTemplateStopID = masters.DeliveryStopID
        INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.Geofences geo 
        ON geo.GeofenceID = details.GeofenceID
        INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.Geofences geo2 
        ON geo2.GeofenceID = details2.GeofenceID
    WHERE clients.RouteTemplateID = DB4010.dbo.EntityStagedData.EntityID
)
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT RouteTemplateID FROM DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplates )
```

This is giving me an error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'EntityData', table 'DB4010.dbo.EntityStagedData'; column does
>   not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to update+Concatenate "EntityData" from the results of the inner Select statement...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "update+Concatenate "EntityData" from the results of the inner Select statement"  Do you mean add 'Entity Data' to the result of the select, or add the existing value of EntityData to the result, or something else?

Comment: Well, EntityData gets appended with the NVARCHAR response from the inner select statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few changes:

- single-letter aliases for readability
- fix to proprietary SQL Server UPDATE FROM syntax
- elimination of uncorrelated WHERE EXISTS clause

You may still need to decide what to do in cases where geo.City etc. contain NULL values. You may need to simply wrap the expression in COALESCE or filter NULL rows out of the join altogether.

```
UPDATE s SET EntityData = 
        geo.City + ' ' + geo.Description + ' ' + geo.Street + ' ' +
        geo2.City + ' ' + geo2.Description + ' ' + geo2.Street
FROM DB4010.dbo.EntityStagedData AS s
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateClients AS c
  ON c.RouteTemplateID = s.EntityID
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplates AS t
  ON t.RouteTemplateID = c.RouteTemplateID
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopMasters AS m
  ON m.RouteTemplateClientID = c.RouteTemplateClientID
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopDetails AS d
  ON d.RouteTemplateStopID = m.PickupStopID
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopDetails AS d2 
  ON d2.RouteTemplateStopID = m.DeliveryStopID
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.Geofences AS geo
  ON geo.GeofenceID = d.GeofenceID
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.Geofences AS geo2 
  ON geo2.GeofenceID = d2.GeofenceID;
```

Comment: This seems to only affect one row rather than every row returned in my original SELECT statement...

Comment: Which row? Is there a where clause you've added that you're not telling us about? Perhaps the way you've written the join means that there can only be a single row? The original SELECT (inside the brackets) couldn't possibly have been run on its own, so you'll need to include more details if you want an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the first section in a [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) statement as such:

```
SET EntityData = COALESCE((     SELECT          geo.City + ' ' + geo.Description 
    + ' ' + geo.Street + ' ' +         geo2.City + ' ' + geo2.Description + ' ' 
    + geo2.Street     
FROM DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplates templates         
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateClients clients ON clients.RouteTemplateID = 
    templates.RouteTemplateID         
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopMasters masters ON 
    masters.RouteTemplateClientID = clients.RouteTemplateClientID         
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopDetails details ON 
    details.RouteTemplateStopID = masters.PickupStopID         
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.RouteTemplateStopDetails details2 ON 
    details2.RouteTemplateStopID = masters.DeliveryStopID         
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.Geofences geo ON geo.GeofenceID = details.GeofenceID         
INNER JOIN DB4010.dbo.Geofences geo2 ON geo2.GeofenceID = details2.GeofenceID     
WHERE clients.RouteTemplateID = DB4010.dbo.EntityStagedData.EntityID ), '')
```

to set the value to a blank value.

If you want to get as much information as possible, wrap each individual portion in `COALESCE` statements to remove `NULL` values, such as:

```
SELECT          COALESCE(geo.City, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(geo.Description, '') ...
```

That way, if one of your values in the sub-select is `NULL`, you won't get a NULL value as a result of the concatenation.